# Empty alias list from keystore in Android app

Tags: java, android, ssl, alias

I am developing a simple android app that issues an HTTP POST with a JSON body to a web server.

To increase security I need to send it over HTTPS so I installed an nginx server with a self signed certificate.

To increase security even more I added a client certificate in the android app request and the appropriate client authentication configuration in the nginx server.

I then created a JKS file containing both: the client and the server public certificates. When I check its contents with keytool I get the following (I just replaced some private info with XXXX). 
It shows 2 entries, as I expected, all good I think.

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

Alias name: XXXXXXXXXXX
Creation date: Jun 4, 2020
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: EMAILADDRESS=XXX, CN=XXX, OU=XX, O=XX, L=XX, ST=XX, C=XX
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=XX, CN=XXX, O=XX, L=XX, ST=XX, C=XX
Serial number: xxxx
Valid from: Fri May 29 23:01:01 CEST 2020 until: Mon May 27 23:01:01 CEST 2030
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  D3:51:13:47:03:2E:54:98:DF:F2:9F:19:89:4A:8B:A0
         SHA1: 7F:DF:89:73:94:95:9E:7C:CA:D9:98:C5:EC:FB:DF:B5:88:A1:B9:30
         SHA256: F3:A5:77:B4:05:73:51:28:B8:85:E3:34:4C:06:A5:BB:C1:E5:A7:04:BE:C1:01:0D:1E:6D:12:E1:9D:E5:FE:4D
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 9C 2D 56 D4 23 4B 1A DC   7D 82 40 58 F4 37 56 41  .-V.#K....@X.7VA
0010: 5B 0F 62 4B                                        [.bK
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 9C 2D 56 D4 23 4B 1A DC   7D 82 40 58 F4 37 56 41  .-V.#K....@X.7VA
0010: 5B 0F 62 4B                                        [.bK
]
]



*******************************************
*******************************************


Alias name: XXXX
Creation date: Jun 4, 2020
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
Issuer: O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=AU
Serial number: 2241b7e2ab0f0463b237ce0e5580c56bd7b56371
Valid from: Fri May 29 13:43:14 CEST 2020 until: Mon May 27 13:43:14 CEST 2030
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  11:9D:F4:18:E0:B9:66:84:69:40:EC:74:D9:6C:AB:A4
         SHA1: 63:3A:48:9E:2A:C8:46:81:AF:C2:EC:44:A6:86:52:17:3C:DC:1E:09
         SHA256: 08:DB:6E:98:DC:C8:98:41:BD:A8:9A:F6:BA:A8:D2:FD:C2:92:BE:AA:43:E0:DD:FB:2C:3F:DB:97:CB:DF:63:A8
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 4096-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BE 15 0C A7 09 23 45 B9   9A 67 A4 7E 61 6B A7 8A  .....#E..g..ak..
0010: 3C 9F B0 37                                        <..7
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: BE 15 0C A7 09 23 45 B9   9A 67 A4 7E 61 6B A7 8A  .....#E..g..ak..
0010: 3C 9F B0 37                                        <..7
]
]
```

But when I try to read the JKS from the android app it doesn´t seem to read anything. For example, no alias are found.

```
 protected void checkKeyStore (KeyStore keyStore) throws KeyStoreException {

        Enumeration aliases = null;
        aliases = clientStore.aliases();
        for (; aliases.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String alias = (String)aliases.nextElement();
            boolean b ;
            b = clientStore.isKeyEntry(alias);
            b = clientStore.isCertificateEntry(alias);

        }
    }
```

The keystore is created and loaded from a file, the code is shown below:

```
protected KeyStore createKeyStore () {
        KeyStore clientStore = null;
        clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(null,null) ;

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String JKSUriToString = prefs.getString("JKSUriToString", "");


        Uri JKSUri= Uri.parse(JKSUriToString);
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileDescriptor fd = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(JKSUri, "r").getFileDescriptor();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);

        clientStore.load(inputStream, certPass.toCharArray());
        return clientStore;
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I created the wrong type of keystore. I didnt see it because I was missing an exception... :( My mistake

The exception said "the keystore is not a PCK12 keystore"
Which is correct
Instead of generating the key this way:

```
keytool -import -keystore keystore.jks -storepass XXXX -noprompt -alias alias1 -file cacert.pem
```

I should have used the parameter pck12

```
keytool -storetype PKCS12 -import -keystore keystore.jks -storepass xXXX -noprompt -alias alias1 -file cacert.pem
```

I leave the question and answer just in case it´s useful for anyone.